# How to get output from Admin Priveleges bash script, called from Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, shell

I'm using code below, to launch bash command, with Admin Privileges. I need to be able to store output in Array,after to use it. How can I get output?

```
 char *command1= "/usr/bin/dscl";

char *args1[] = {".","-read","/SharePoints/FolderName","directory_path",nil};

    FILE *pipe = nil;

                            err = AuthorizationCreate(nil,
                              kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment,
                              kAuthorizationFlagDefaults,
                              &authorizationRef);

        err = AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(authorizationRef,
                                               command,
                                              kAuthorizationFlagDefaults,
                                              args1,
                                              &pipe);
```

Output should be folder -Path of some shared folder.
How can I get it, and to store in Array?

P.S. In NSTask is possible to do with NSPipe, but here is File type.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why not redirect output into tmp file. Then much simplier to write script that processes file. Good luck.

Comment: I'm new in programming. Can you tell it with details? I'm running this script from my Cocoa APP, with admin privileges. And I need that output. But can't get output from my APP

Comment: I think you need to pass a valid file structure for the communicationsPipe argument instead of a pointer to nil.

Comment: What you mean with saying pass a valid file structure? I tried something NSFileHandle , it won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read from](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/fread.3.html) the POSIX file handle (`FILE *`) that `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges` returned to you. Don't forget to close it when you're done.