# What is a FILE * type in Cocoa,and how properly use it?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, posix

I'm trying to run Bash commands from my Cocoa APP. And receive the output. I'm executing all that commands, with Admin Privilege.
[How to get output from Admin Priveleges bash script, called from Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710068/how-to-get-output-from-admin-priveleges-bash-script-called-from-cocoa)

I guess I need FILE * type to store output, but I don't know how to use it.

**What is FILE * type? And how should I use it?**

Comment: `FILE*` isn't Cocoa. It's POSIX C.

Comment: ok thanks. and how it should be used in Cocoa?

Comment: @User1234 the same as in C. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FILE *` is a C type and it hasn't got anything to do with Cocoa. It is a handle for an opened file. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  FILE *file;
  file = fopen("myfile.txt", "w"); // open file
  if (!file) { // file couldn't be opened
    return 1;
  }
  fputs("fopen example", file); // write to file
  fclose(file);
  return 0;
}
```

---

In Cocoa, you should normally use `NSString`'s and `NSData`'s `writeToURL:atomically:encoding:error:` and `writeToURL:atomically:` methods, respectively.

Comment: Reason I'm asking.. is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710068/how-to-get-output-from-admin-priveleges-bash-script-called-from-cocoa  . I need to receive output from bash commands. Can you help me with that?

Comment: After using the code from that question, read from `pipe` using the `fread` function.

Comment: So I need to create a file, and write to it, after read it? No way to read it without writing to file? or writing in temporary?

Comment: Here is an example: https://gist.github.com/1281162. You read directly from `pipe`. Note that on UNIX systems, pipes are used the same way as files.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I'm still confused. FILE * nil , how it works? I'm trying to store output in NSArray, but can't figure out

Comment: If you have an Idea how to read that from Pipe, and add it to Array, please help, I need it. Thanks

Comment: @WTPany idea why I can't get output ?

Comment: @User1234: Repeatedly asking somebody to help you will not make them more likely to do so. Be patient, and consider looking in the documentation in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

FILE is an ANSI C structure is used for file handling. fopen function return a file pointer. This pointer, points to a structure that contains information about the file, such as the location of a buffer, the current character position in the buffer, whether the file is being read or written, and whether errors or end of file have occurred. Users don't need to know the details, because the definitions obtained from stdio.h include a structure declaration called FILE. The only declaration needed for a file pointer is exemplified by

```
FILE *fp;
FILE *fopen(char *name, char *mode);
```

This says that fp is a pointer to a FILE, and fopen returns a pointer to a FILE. Notice that
FILE is a type name, like int, not a structure tag; it is defined with a typedef.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   FILE * pFile;
   char buffer [100];

   pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt" , "r");
   if (pFile == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
   else
   {
     while ( ! feof (pFile) )
     {
       if ( fgets (buffer , 100 , pFile) != NULL )
         fputs (buffer , stdout);
     }
     fclose (pFile);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

This example reads the content of a text file called myfile.txt and sends it to the standard output stream.