# Run a new task, depending on the output of the first task

Tags: objective-c

I have build a little app which works fine, but i need a bit more functionality.

Here is the code which already works.

```
NSTask *task1 = [[NSTask alloc] init];

[task1 setLaunchPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"command-line tool" ofType:@""]];

[task1 setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"1",@"10",nil]];

[task1 launch];
[task1 waitUntilExit];

NSTask *task2 = [[NSTask alloc] init];

[task2 setLaunchPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"command-line tool" ofType:@""]];

[task2 setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"20",nil]];

[task2 launch];
[task2 waitUntilExit];
```

What i want to do is: **The code should run a new task depending on the output value of the first task.**

Something like: **If the output value from first task1 is "10" run task2 which will change the value to "20" if it is already "20" exit.**

Any reference example would be useful. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to receive output of NSTask in Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699507/how-to-receive-output-of-nstask-in-cocoa)

Comment: Thanks, I know that answer and i've already tried it, it gives me the output in hex, but i don't know how to run a new task depending on that data.

Comment: Can you explain what you have, what you want and where the problem is?

Comment: I want to change the values depending of the previous value. I have four values, if the value it "10" it should be changed to "20" if it's "30" change it to "40". The first part "task1" which reads the value and the code you've linked I get the output value, but I don't know how to run the second part "task2" to change the value to "20" if the fist value is "10"